# How to tackle skewness and output file size in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am facing skewness problem, when I am trying to join 2 datasets. One of data partition ( the column I am trying to perform the join operation) has skewness than rest of the partition and due to this one of a final output part file is 40 times greater than rest of the output part files.
I am using `Scala, Apache spark` for performing my calculation and file format used is `parquet`.

So I am looking for 2 solutions:

- First is how can I tackle the skewness as time taken to process that
  skewed data is taking a lot of time. (For the skewed data I have tried Broadcasting but it did not helped )
- Seconds is how can I make all the final output part files stored
  within a  256 MB range. I have tried a property
  spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 but it is not making any
  difference.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Skewness is a common problem when dealing with data.
To handle it, there is a technique called **salting** exists.

First, you may check out [this video by Ted Malaska](https://youtu.be/kv8kWvk1xyY?t=1018) to get the intuition about salting.

Second, examine [his repository](https://github.com/TedBear42/spark_training/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/malaska/spark/training/salted/SaltedExample.scala) oh this theme.

I think that each issue with skewness has its own method to solve it. 
Hope these materials will help you.